# form for inserting using php and pdo

Tags: php, forms, pdo, insert

I am losing my mind on this and I could really use some direction. Just trying to learn PDO along with PHP and failing to understand the logic. I keep trying to find something online that shows a good example of the flow for this test attempt and I'm having a real hard time.

Could someone, even if you have to flame the heck out of me (although like anyone, I'd prefer you not), give me some direction on what I'm doing horribly wrong? I'm building this to start my understanding. There's plenty of info on using mysqli but not pdo and it's driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance. Here's the code:

```
<?php

# connection info to the db
$host = "--shadowed--";
$dbname = "--shadowed--";
$user = "--shadowed--";
$pass = "--shadowed--";

# pdo options/attributes
$opt = array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); // not getting errors
# data source name
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";


# basic pdo connection (with added option for error handling)
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    try {
        $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO data (name,email,phone,detail,cost) VALUES (:name,:email,:phone,:detail,:cost)");

        $STH->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $STH->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
        $STH->bindParam(':detail', $detail);
        $STH->bindParam(':cost', $cost);


        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $detail = $_POST['detail'];
        $cost = $_POST['cost'];


        $STH->execute();
        echo $STH; // attempted to echo back the data, but nothing happens


    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); // no errors
    }
}

echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
echo '<p>Enter the below information if you want to live:</p>';
echo 'Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />';
echo 'E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br />';
echo 'Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br />';
echo 'Order will be generated randomly from class (once built)<br />';
echo 'Description: <input type="text" name="detail"><br />';
echo 'Cost: <input type="text" name="cost"><br />';

echo '<input type="submit" value="Do-It"></form>';

# close the connection  
$DBH = null;
?>
```

## ------------- Final Code after Resolution Reached -------------

## ------------- Final Code after Resolution Reached -------------

(*still a newb so can't answer my own question currently*)

So first off, I didn't come up with this... it's a mix of everyone here really. I appreciate everyone's help and time with this while I try to learn all the missing links from my knowledge.

The main issues seems to be that when I used my original attempt to utilize `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`, it didn't actually do or send anything. No errors... no database issues... just a bunch of nothing. We removed that to find it was holding back ( ty @Fred ). Although this didn't change how the code works, it became more efficient using @hjpotter92 suggestion. Then we looked how to submit using this single page. I ended up using a mix of @Fred's and @david strachan suggestions as neither was giving me the right reaction, then I added an if/else statement to perform the check and if it passed, run the try/catch.

It's no work of art, but I learned quite a bit and appreciate the help. Also, I think it will be nice to get something out there people can bump into to see a full example. If any of you guys have any additional suggestions, please let me know. Along with learning the base knowledge, I'm also reviewing how to help against sql injection (which may not be fully covered in this test).

```
    #------------------ Working Code ------------------#

    # pdo options/attributes
    $opt = array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    # data source name
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";


    # basic pdo connection (with added option for error handling)
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        if (!$_POST['name'] || !$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['phone'] || !$_POST['detail'] || !$_POST['cost']) {
            echo "<p>Please supply all of the data! You may press your back button to attempt again minion!</p>";
            exit;
        } else {

            try {        
                $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
                $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO data (name,email,phone,detail,cost) VALUES (:name,:email,:phone,:detail,:cost)");

                $STH->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
                $STH->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
                $STH->bindParam(':phone', $_POST['phone']);
                $STH->bindParam(':detail', $_POST['detail']);
                $STH->bindParam(':cost', $_POST['cost']);

                $STH->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>";

        }
    }

    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
    echo '<p>Enter the below information if you want to live:</p>';
    echo 'Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />';
    echo 'E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br />';
    echo 'Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br />';
    echo 'Order will be generated randomly<br />';
    echo 'Description: <input type="text" name="detail"><br />';
    echo 'Cost: <input type="text" name="cost"><br />';

    echo '<input type="submit" value="Do-It"></form>';



    # close the connection  
    $DBH = null;
    ?>
```

Comment: So are you having an actual problem, or just looking for general code advice?

Comment: Your form action is empty.

Comment: @Fred - if there's no form action specified, it will post back to the same URL.

Comment: @andrewsi - same as using `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` then, right?

Comment: General code advice is definitely appreciated. As for the no form action, I thought the isset($_POST['submit']) was suppose to of submitted the data to the database. My db is still empty and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: @Fred - `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will just give you the script name; if you leave the action empty, it will submit to the same page but also include any querysting that's present.

Comment: @SiLeNCeD Try omitting/bypassing your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` to see what it does (comment it out) or even using `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` - (if NOT set). Only thing that comes to mind to "troubleshoot". Might be the `isset` playing tricks on you.

Comment: @Fred - Thanks... that at least gave me a reaction. So initially it tried to send data and found that the name isn't allowed to be null (expected - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null). I checked the db and now I'm seeing some data.
So here's my newby question of the day. How can I fix my form to only send on submit (I'm obviously not using the isset function correctly). Any suggestions on a solid method (seems like all of the posts I read today, everyone is doing something different, which is what made getting this far so difficult.

Comment: @SiLeNCeD Great, now we're getting somewhere. I'd replace the `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` with a field validation function instead. Making sure all fields have been filled and if so, then the insert function will go into effect.

Comment: @SiLeNCeD Have you tried `hjpotter92's` one-liner method? `$STH->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);` etc.? That also could help in the validation process.

Comment: I did. It felt nice to run into that earlier, but then I had changed it back because I didn't know if it was part of the problem lol (I'm going to update the resolution once I find a suitable replacement for the isset). I'm probably trying to learn too much at once, but I'm stubborn like that. I'm looking up the field validation function stuff now to see where it takes me.

Comment: @SiLeNCeD I'll post a validation process that could be of help.

Comment: @SiLeNCeD Another thing you could try is to declare your POSTed fields underneath `$pass = "--shadowed--";`

Comment: @SiLeNCeD Glad it worked out for you. Maybe an `upvote` for the useful stuff from everyone? ;-) cheers

Comment: Trust me... I want to upvote (and I definitely would have before this was finished), but it says I have to have 15 rep first. I don't have any type of options to give credit :(

Comment: @SiLeNCeD Right on bro (I'm assuming you're a `bro` lol)! I'm glad to hear you have it working the way you wanted it to. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

To check if the request is POST type use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` [**Documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
// Get POST variables
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; 
$name = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['detail']) ? $_POST['detail'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['cost']) ? $_POST['cost'] : '';
If($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {  
        Try{
   Remainder of code
```

Comment: So I attempted adding the above and squeezing my data into the Try. That allowed everything thru with empty data. Removed the top part and so did that. What I did to make this work for me was mix your $_SERVER Request method with Fred's if statement and made a slight modification (about to post). Thanks @david strachan for pointing me in the right direction. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the ordering from the following

```
$STH->bindParam(':name', $name);
$STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
$STH->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$STH->bindParam(':detail', $detail);
$STH->bindParam(':cost', $cost);


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$cost = $_POST['cost'];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$cost = $_POST['cost'];

$STH->bindParam(':name', $name);
$STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
$STH->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$STH->bindParam(':detail', $detail);
$STH->bindParam(':cost', $cost);
```

or simply use:

```
$STH->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
$STH->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$STH->bindParam(':phone', $_POST['phone']);
$STH->bindParam(':detail', $_POST['detail']);
$STH->bindParam(':cost', $_POST['cost']);
```

Comment: I actually tried that at one point too thinking it made sense, but it still didn't send anything. I'll try it again (I've been fighting over each part of this most of the morning).

Comment: Tried that... no change. I feel like I'm missing something larger here. I commented out the var = $_POST data and used the combined method (like I said, seemed to make sense). It's still not sending the data. Action-wise, I don't have any other pages setup right now. I added a placeholder (#) just to keep it on the same page. Do I need something else there?.

Comment: Although this is not the answer to the problem, it is good advice and I've updated my code for it. Thank you @hjpotter92 for pointing it out. I appreciate that.

Comment: Quick question (I hope)... if I setup a class... should I integrate the `$STH->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'])` into the class directly or no?

Example:
`class Client {
  public $name; 
  public function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $_POST['name'];
  }
}`

Comment: @SiLeNCeD What kind of class?

Comment: (sorry... was having some issues with showing it as code in my comment heh... the example from my last entry)

Comment: If it is a small project, I don't think you'd need a class @SiLeNCeD Although, you're always welcome to ask a separate question if you "actually" face any problems.

Comment: Ok @hjpotter92 ... I appreciate that. The project will grow into a usable program... but I'll try some stuff first and see where it takes me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer** but a form validation function that could be of help.

I'm sure there are multiple ways of achieving this, but it will surely get you started.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$cost = $_POST['cost'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone))) || empty($detail))) || empty($cost)) {
// do something
   exit;
    }

if (!empty($name) || !empty($email) || !empty($phone))) || !empty($detail))) || !empty($cost)) {
// do something else
// for example, write the data in database
   exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: So I used the method above just as is and it gave me the same result as what sent me here... didn't do anything. Instead of the $_POST Submit method I used David's method above and then mixed it up with your solution. About to post the results. I appreciate all the help you've given me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you let the user send a blank form? Handle the "please supply all of the data" warning on the client side with javascript. Don't allow the form to get past javascript without fulfilling all of the requirements.